# 404 errors in webmaster tools on URLs containing swedish characters like å, ä ö

Tags: google-search-console, url-encoding

How can I handle the Swedish, Danish and Russian characters in URLs so that Webmaster tools would stop returning 404 errors.

Note that opening the URL using the character "as is" is fine, but Google encodes the characters such as:

`ä` becomes `%25C3%25A4` and `ö` becomes `%25C3%25B6`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `%25C3%25A4` is "doubly" encoded, so for some reason Google thinks your URLs contain the _literal_ string `%C3%A4`, not `ä`. (?)

Comment: Probably so. What can I do in this case? I mean is it best all together to replace these characters?

Comment: Well, Google doesn't normally get this sort of thing wrong, so it would seem that it's picking these (incorrectly encoded and broken) URLs up from somewhere? As Matthew suggests in his answer, _where_ is Google getting these URLs from?

Comment: Yeah I found out where these are being picked from. These has been placed by other website owner obviously, how can I control that?

Answer (score 1):

Can you correct the broken link at the source? Also, have you confirmed the source of the error is incorrect (are you sure that the link is really broken and this is not a crawler issue)?

To find out the origin of the link, click on the 404 error and then look at the "Linked From" tab. Check out the links listed there and see if the links pointing to your site are actually broken or not. If they are broken, hopefully you can correct at the source (either on your site or by reaching out to the other site).

[image]

You can also look at redirecting URLs with special characters by using regex. Here are some links to other Q&As that could help with that in htaccess:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18641871/how-to-handle-special-characters-like-and-in-htaccess-rules
- https://moz.com/community/q/redirecting-special-characters-in-htaccess-and-web-config#reply_149753

Though, I've also had an easier time catching these errors on the 404 error page itself. You can write server-side code to check the URL before the 404 response is fired to see if it matches one of these characters. If there is a match, redirect before the 404 is returned.